# Detect any user action event

Tags: javascript

How can a function be executed whenever this is any user activity such as moving or scrolling the mouse or pressing a key?  I am thinking something similar to the following, however, likely other events will be required.  Ideally, jQuery would not be required.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', resetTimer);
window.addEventListener('scroll', resetTimer);
document.addEventListener('keydown', resetTimer);
```

The purpose is for implementing a JavaScript based page rotator that will start after X seconds of user inactivity.

Comment: Seems like the code shown already answers your own question. Is there another one?

Comment: @charlietfl  Started to doubt myself.  Been a while since I've done much JavaScript, and when I had been, I got in the lazy habit of relying on jQuery.   Think I have the main events I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several events you could listen to, I believe these should cover the most:

- `mousedown` to capture click events
- `mousemove` to capture cursor movements
- `touchstart` to capture taps (on touchscreens)
- `keydown` to capture key events
- `scroll` to capture scrolling

See demo code below.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', viewEvent);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', viewEvent);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', viewEvent);
document.addEventListener('scroll', viewEvent);
document.addEventListener('keydown', viewEvent);

function viewEvent(evt){
  document.getElementById('viewEvent').innerHTML = evt.type;
}
```

```css
#viewEvent{
  position: fixed;
  padding: .2em;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewEvent"></div>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
dummy text<br>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas,  Willing to show `addEventListener` examples?  I've got several already working, but scroll for instance is giving me a hard time.

Comment: My demo code, now updated, seems to work fine with `document.addEventListener('scroll', viewEvent)`. Note that capturing the scroll event may depend on which element is actually scrolled (a google search points to issues with this).

Comment: Thanks Tomas,  I actually misunderstood, and thought "scroll" was scrolling the mouse instead of making an element scroll, and I had it working already, but didn't realize so.  Also, I hadn't originally included the `touchstart` event and am glad you pointed it out.